# Retrieve contents from a php file using json data type and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have used ajax post with datatype json to fetch content from a php file and display. But I'm new to json and I was unable to get content from the php file. only numeric value is fetched. Here is the code I'm using

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'events_fetch.php',
  data: {eventID:calEvent.id,action:'LOAD_SINGLE_EVENT_BASED_ON_EVENT_ID'},
  dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function(ed) { 
  alert(ed);
});
```

I used the above function to get content from the php file and alerted. But alert not working.Kindly guide what iam doing wrong.Here is my php code

**events_fetch.php**

```
$eventID= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["eventID"]);
$qry="SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `id`='$eventID'";
$res=mysql_query($qry);
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$strtdate=$fetch['start-date'];
$strttime=$fetch['start-time'];


$retValue=array($strtdate,$strttime);
echo $retValue;
```

Comment: You have to apply `json_encode` on output: `echo json_encode($retValue);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your events_fetch.php as below

```
$eventID= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["eventID"]);
$qry="SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE `id`='$eventID'";
$res=mysql_query($qry);
$fetch=mysql_fetch_array($res);

$strtdate=$fetch['start-date'];
$strttime=$fetch['start-time'];


$retValue=array($strtdate,$strttime);
echo json_encode($retValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply `json_encode` function on output:

```
echo json_encode($retValue);
```